# Find values of $a$ for which the integral converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For my homework, I need to find the values of $a$ for which the following integral converges.  $$\int_0^{1/e}\frac{x^a}{\ln{x}} \,dx$$
I've tried using integration by parts, but only got (seemingly) more complex integrands of of it. It'd be a major help if anyone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the substitution $$t=-\ln(x)\;\; or\;\; x=e^{-t}$$

your integral will have the same nature as

$$I=\int_1^{+\infty}f(t)dt=\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-(1+a)t}}{t}dt$$

$$ (1+a)<0 \implies \lim_{t\to+\infty}f(t)=+\infty$$
$$\implies I\; diverges$$

$$(1+a)=0 \implies f(t)=\frac 1t$$
$$\implies I \; diverges$$

$$(1+a)>0\implies \lim_{t\to+\infty}t^2f(t)=0$$
$$\implies I \;\; converges$$

We conclude that $$\boxed{I\;\; converges \;\;\iff a>-1}$$

Comment: This argument shows not only that a real $a$ achieves convergence iff $a>-1$, but that a complex $a$ achieves convergence iff $\Re a>-1$.